# My pasta maker roller has warped

Tags: pasta

My son was making pasta but stuffed a huge dollop into the roller, which has then caused the roller to roll in an oval shape rather than smoothly; so now I get horizontal 'stripes' in the dough from where it rolls thinner in some places than others because the roller gets thick, the  thin again in one turn.

Does anyone know how I can get the shape back in the roller, or stop it shifting backwards and forwards on its bar if this is what's happening?

It's a new machine and I'd like to save it if I can!

Comment: Depending how new it is, you might want to check with the company, as you might be able to get a replacement under warranty

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to first establish what's bent.
If the roller cylinders are solid steel, then possibly an axle. If they're hollow, then the cylinder itself is more likely.

If the axle is bent, then there's a chance you could bend it back to approximately straight again, depending on what equipment you have access to - though it will always be a weak point. If the cylinder is distorted you can probably forget it.
Time for a new roller.

Comment: As stripes were mentioned, I suspect it’s the axle.  The roller itself being dented would lead to a bump each rotation instead of stripes, unless it somehow deformed evenly across the whole side

Comment: I believe Joe is correct here, an axle defect would apply across the entire roller's surface, whereas a roller defect would not.

Comment: Until the OP comes back with further explanation/pictures, all we have is guesswork, hence how this answer was framed.